# Possible to Install Hyper-V via Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 14.04

I am new to the Ubuntu world and have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my home PC. I was just wondering if it's possible to install a version of Hyper-V?

just looking to play around with Hyper-V

i.e. Is there a `sudo apt-get install` command I can use?

if not .. no biggie

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install the Hyper-V management software on Linux. It is a Windows virtualization system from Microsoft. The kernel already has drivers to run as a guest OS under Windows though. You can install the `virtualbox-qt` package though, if you want an easy app for creating virtual machines on Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks man,already have VirtualBox installed....which is how i created the Ubuntu vm

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Hyper-V on Ubuntu since it is exclusively for Windows machines.

> Hyper-V, codenamed Viridian and formerly known as Windows Server
>   Virtualization, is a native hypervisor; it can create virtual machines
>   on x86-64 systems. Starting with Windows 8, Hyper-V supersedes Windows
>   Virtual PC as the hardware virtualization component of the client
>   editions of Windows NT

You can read more about it [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V)